# Rebuilding Object property after aggregate Expression

Tags: c#, linq

I am building a system of filters to manipulate a simple collection that looks like:

```
public class ProcessedData
{
    public byte ProcessId { get; set; }
    public List<EventsData> EventsData { get; set; } = new List<EventsData>();
}
```

And `EventsData` object has its id property inside something like:

```
public class EventData
{
     public byte EventDataId { get; set; }
}
```

Now the idea is simple, I have a collection of selected ProcessId and EventId in form of the two list like:

```
public List<byte> SelectedProcessFilter { get; set; }
public List<byte> SelectedEventFilter { get; set; }
```

So I have prepared aggregate where conditions function what looks like:

```
    public IEnumerable<ProcessedData> DataFilter(IEnumerable<ProcessedData> preprocessedData, Expression<Func<ProcessedData, bool>>[] filters)
    {
        if (filters != null)
        {
            preprocessedEvents = filters.Aggregate(preprocessedData, (current, filter) => current.Where(filter.Compile()));
        }

        return preprocessedEvents.ToList();
    }
```

And now i can declare where conditions something like:

```
    private Expression<Func<ProcessedData, bool>>[] BuildPredicate()
    {
        var predicates = new List<Expression<Func<ProcessedData, bool>>>();

        if (SelectedProcessFilter != null && SelectedProcessFilter .Any())
        {
            predicates.Add(data => SelectedProcessFilter.Contains(data.ProcessId));
        }

        if (SelectedEventFilter != null && SelectedEventFilter.Any())
        {
            predicates.Add(data => SelectedEventFilter.Any(value => data.EventsData.Any(target => target.EventDataId == (byte)value.Value)));
        }

        return predicates.ToArray();
    }
```

Usage is simple just:

```
IEnumerable<ProcessedData> filteredPreprocessedData = service.DataFilter(preprocessedEvents, BuildPredicate());
```

And basically works, but there is one thins when i filter on EventsDataId, it checks if such value is in that property only, Is it possible to fit somehow possibility to rebuild such property so it will contain only selected EventId ?

Comment: you can try a computed read only property that checks if eventId exists

Comment: Why are you using expressions when you're just compiling them into delegates?  If you want to have delegates, just use them from the start.

Comment: You can't rebuild the `ProcessedData` object with LINQ (used properly) but you could build a new `ProcessedData` object that filtered `EventsData` if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now as what i did, I fallowed NetMage advise and just made a copy of object with new properties values.